# SQL conditional sum across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum

I have following three tables

**1. Product Master (pm)**

- Product_Code
- Product_Name
- Product_Category (Books,
  Stationary, Journals, Magazines)

**2. Order Master (om)**

- Order_ID
- Order_No
- Order_Date

**3. Order Lines (ol)**

- Order_Line_ID
- Order_ID
- Product_Code
- Qty
- Amount

Now I need following columns in record set:

> om.order_no, om.order_date, sum(ol.qty) for Books, sum(ol.amount) for Books,  sum(ol.qty) for Stationary,  sum(ol.amount) for Stationary,   sum(ol.qty) for Journals,  sum(ol.amount) for Journals,   sum(ol.qty) for Magazines,  sum(ol.amount) for Magazines.

Please help in writing conditional sum. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give this a try,

```
SELECT  a.Order_NO,
        a.Order_Date,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.Product_Category = 'Books' THEN b.Qty ELSE 0 END) totalBooks,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.Product_Category = 'Books' THEN b.Amount ELSE 0 END) totalBooks_Amount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.Product_Category = 'Stationary' THEN b.Qty ELSE 0 END) totalStationary,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.Product_Category = 'Stationary' THEN b.Qty ELSE 0 END) totalStationary_Amount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.Product_Category = 'Journals' THEN b.Qty ELSE 0 END) totalJournals,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.Product_Category = 'Journals' THEN b.Qty ELSE 0 END) totalJournals_Amount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.Product_Category = 'Magazines' THEN b.Qty ELSE 0 END) totalMagazines,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.Product_Category = 'Magazines' THEN b.Qty ELSE 0 END) totalMagazines_Amount
FROM    OrderMaster a
        INNER JOIN OrderLines b 
            ON a.Order_ID = b.Order_ID
        INNER JOIN ProductMaster c
            ON b.Product_Code = c.Product_Code
GROUP   BY a.Order_NO, a.Order_Date
```